# How can I format a date into a moment.js compartible date?

Tags: momentjs

This code is working:

```js
var start = moment([2017, 10, 5]);
var end   = moment([2017, 10, 10]);
var result = end.from(start); 

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

With this code I expect the same result as in the code above:

```js
var start_input = "05.10.2017";
var end_input= "10.10.2017";

var start = moment(start_input, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate();
var end = moment(end_input, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate();
var result = end.from(start); 

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

But there is a mistake...

Comment: Just remove  toDate() it works

Comment: @NitinDhomse Yes, this is working! Great!

Comment: [`from`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) is a method of moment library, you are trying to use it on a JavaScript Date (see [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) docs)